# In Android Application Portrait Mode To Change Landscape Mode My EditText Value is Clear

Tags: android

In Android Application Portrait Mode To Change Landscape Mode My EditText Value is Clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is rotation happened activity always restarts.

so keep this in mind, persist the variables while rotating from portrait to landscape and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

EditText should automagically save the text value on orientation change. I can think of two reasons why it would be cleared:

1) you are implementing onSaveInstanceState, but failing to call super.onSaveInstanceState
2) the editText does not have a valid ID. An example of an editText without a valid ID is a programmatically created editText such as adding an editText to an AlertDialog. This can be solved by creating a simple layout as in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText android:text="Stateful"
android:id="@+id/EditText01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

And inflating the layout as in:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflater();
final View myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
builder.setTitle("About");
builder.setMessage(alertMessage+"Version: "+versionName);
builder.setView(myView);
AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
```

Hope that helps.